# Real time issue in qt/c++ app

Tags: c++, qt, real-time

I have wrote an app in Qt/C++ using Qt creator. What's happening is that in Qt creator the app works fine (file transfer between android and mac).

As soon as I'm generating the app and run it out of Qt creator some files copy is failing all the time.

I was thinking that it's coming from how we run the debug compared to the official app.

Is there any behavior issue between:

```
if(item)
    CopyFile(LocalPath, Android_device);
```

and

```
if(item) {
   ret = CopyFile(LocalPath, Android_device);
   if(ret != 0)
       ...
```

I do not ask in case of coding difference but mostly in case 1, is the app is not waiting the feedback of Copy and in case, do we need to wait the feedback before continuing as I introduce a "if"

The app is not using multithreading it's just a basic Qt/C++ app

Thanks

Comment: Whether or not you evaluate the return value of CopyFile does not make a 'waiting' or 'not waiting' difference. If there is a difference, it is in the part your are not showing us... if(ret != 0).... But I would first see, if there is a difference in your environment. Does your QtCreator set some environment variables, which you don't have outside the creator?

Comment: When you run the App from outside of Qt Creator, your working directory changes which might break relative paths. Can you see which files are not copied properly?

Comment: @Simon: in terms of MTP : files copy works between the app and the device. it's the recursivity in case I move a folder which is not working. by thinking of this the only thing I think right away is that the evaluation of what is inside the folder I'm copying from my mac to android device return that there is no files inside when running out of Qt creator and the app correctly handle the recursivity when inside QTcreator. I have mostly handle all error and no erros happends

Comment: sounds like you are using a QT TCP socket.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you were depending on the working directory of your application. Don't do that. When you start it from Qt Creator, it sets a specific working directory that will be usually different from whatever working directory is set by the shell or Explorer or Finder.

Answer (score 1):

First version gets a return value and throws it away, second version uses the return value. There is no difference in what `CopyFile(LocalPath, Android_device);` does.